# Detect custom annotation on spring bean constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, components

I don't know if it's possible, but I want to know if the method used for constructing a bean has a specific annotation. In my case I am writing a library to wrap a Spring proxy around a spring bean. However this piece of code I am trying to wrap in a proxy is autogenerated using the [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin), which means I cannot just add the decorator directly to the given class.

The current setup I trying to use is:
Given an object I want as a bean:

```
public class CustomComponent {
    // Some logic, in my case, this component is a piece of autogenerated code, so I cannot modify this.
}
```

I have created a annotation like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomDecorator {
}
```

So when I want to create the bean I do the following:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomBeanConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    @CustomDecorator
    CustomComponent customComponent() {
        return new CustomComponent();
    }
}
```

In my library I am currently using the BeanPostProcessor to get a hold of the bean directly after   initialization, and this is where I wanted to get a hold of the bean, but only if the construction of the bean was decorated with the CustomDecorator.

```
public class BeanProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if(bean constructor has @CustomDecorator){
            Add proxy advise;
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

I have tried via. some reflection utilities, and via the bean factory, but it seems as if I am unable to do it.

Is this possible? how can it be done?

Comment: The problem is you are intercepting the constructed bean **not** the definition of the bean. Your only hope would be an AspectJ advice to I intercept the creation of the bean, or apply the proxy in your `@Bean` method when created (instead of adding an annotation). You could create a utility method/helper for that.

Comment: Damn, was my worry. I hoped since that `@Primary` can be found, it would be the same for custom annotations.

Comment: The `@Primary` is different as that is for bean configuration and detected early on in the process by the configuration processor.